# Override WriteJson with JSON.NET lib

Tags: c#, json.net, overriding

I have a class Person which looks like that:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Hobbies { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Country {get; set;}
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

What I want is to override the WriteJson function. I already managed to do the ReadJson. I want my WriteJson to write a json string which will look like that:
The final goal is to perform to write Lists of any other type of object.

```
@"{
          'Columns':['FirstName','LastName','Hobbies','Age','Country','Address','Phone','Gender'],
          'Rows':[
                  ['X', 'Y', 'Cuisine', '35', 'France', 'unknown', 'unknown', 'male'],
                  ['W', 'Z', 'Jouer', '43', 'France', 'unknown', 'unknown', 'male'],
                  ...]
 }";
```

My WriteJson is like that:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        IEnumerable collectionObj = value as IEnumerable;
        writer.WriteStartArray();

        foreach (object curObj in collectionObj)
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            serializer.Serialize(writer, curObj);
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
```

When compiling, I still have an error (I think it is because of my WriteStartArray) can you please confirm me what is going wrong and how can I override my WriteJson function to do what I want?

here is the error I am getting:

> Additional information: Token StartObject in state ObjectStart would result in an invalid JSON object. Path '[0]'.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `foreach` loop, you first have to write the property's name. Your code would write something like this which isn't valid JSON, indeed:

```
[
  {
    // serialized "curObj" goes here, for example:
    { "a": "b" }
  }
]
```

Before `serializer.Serialize(writer, curObj);` you have to write

```
writer.WritePropertyName("PropertyName");
```

so the JSON would look like this:

```
[
  {
    // serialized "curObj" goes here, AFTER property name:
    "PropertyName": { "a": "b" }
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks. So my propertyname here is columns and rows.
Then I can write my serialize data
Does json string begin with a { [property: content] } or it is like that : [ { property: content} ] (I am a new user of json.net so if you can confirm me the way you will write it.

Comment: Well, it's JavaScript syntax. So an array consists of `[value, value, ...]` and an object of `{ propertyname: value, propertyname: value, ... }`. And `value` can be an array or object again. So in your case, it's `[ { name: value, ... }, { ... } ]`.